# Display div when clicking on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've added three pictures. Look at them please.
[image]

What is the best solution to create something like this? I would create     after each row a big container and this container is collapsed. After clicking on one of the 3 overlying containers I would fill the container with the text and show it. But what happens when the display can't show 3 divs in a row, because I will use flex boxes? Is there a better solution with much less jquery?

Comment: Best solution: Spending time experimenting with `CSS` or maybe doing some research.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is a good place to start:
https://jsfiddle.net/547ec3bx/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element">
    </div>
    <div class="element">
    </div>
    <div class="element">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element">
    </div>
    <div class="element">
    </div>
    <div class="element">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="element">
    </div>
    <div class="element">
    </div>
    <div class="element">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('.row').forEach((element, index) => {
  element.style.order = index * 2;
});

document.querySelectorAll('.element').forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', event => {
    var newRow = document.createElement('div');
    newRow.classList.add('row');
    newRow.style.order = +event.currentTarget.parentNode.style.order + 1;
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');
    newElement.classList.add('element');
    newRow.appendChild(newElement);
    event.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(newRow);
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.element {
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.row {
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to solve this problem , like this ....
 html code:

```
<div id="a"> 
  <a href="#e" onclick="goB()"><h3>wellcome</h3></a>

</div>
<div id="b">
  <a href = "#er" onclick="goA"> <h3>hello...</h3> </a>
</div>
```

javascript code in external file

```
function goB()
{
  document.getElementById("a").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("b").style.display="block";
}
function 
{
  document.getElementById("b").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("a").style.display="block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a div and set its display to Hidden.
Get onclick event for a particular div and set the display property to block

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
     document.getElementById("click").onclick = function(){
       document.getElementById("div-1").style.display = "block";
     };
});
```

```css
.row
{
    width:100%;
}

.one-third
{  
  width:33.33333%;
  float:left;
  padding:30px 0;

}

.full-width
{
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrap>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="click" class="one-third">
      Column 1-Click Me
      </div>
     <div class="one-third">
      Column 2  
    </div>
     <div class="one-third">
       Column 3
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="full-width" id="div-1">Full width Div</div>
 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one-third">
      Column 1
      </div>
     <div class="one-third">
       Column 2
      </div>
     <div class="one-third">
       Column 3
      </div>
    </div>
```